# Javascript looping if statements for a text adventure

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, adventure

I'm trying to build the simplest text adventure possible by looping if statements with my `startGame()` function. How can I make it work? or am I barking up the wrong tree?

```
let m = 1;

function startGame() {
  if (m === 1){
    document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = "START PAGE"; 
    document.querySelector("#btn").value = 'Go to map 2';
    document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", map2);
    function map2() {
      m = 2;
    }
  } else if (m === 2) {
      document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = "SUCCESS!!!"; 
  } else {
      document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = "Nothing works";
  }
}

startGame()
```

Comment: there is no loop here

Comment: @andymccullough He means series of ifs I think

Comment: please provide exactly the problem and desired output along with some code

Comment: `How can I make it work?` You first need to tell us what the problem is

Comment: I think he is asking "well I have this series of ifs, now I want to run it in a loop so that it won't freeze the browser". From what I understand he wants to do different things based on the `m` value. And the `m` value changes as the user plays the game

Answer (score 1):

The first problem you have is that when `map2()` is called, the logic in `startGame` is not re-evaluated, only `m` changes, not things that use `m` to determine things.

You can fix this by manually calling `startGame` again:

```js
let m = 1;

function startGame() {
  if (m === 1){
    document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = "START PAGE"; 
    document.querySelector("#btn").value = 'Go to map 2';
    document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", map2);
    function map2() {
      m = 2;
      startGame();
    }
  } else if (m === 2) {
      document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = "SUCCESS!!!"; 
  } else {
      document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = "Nothing works";
  }
}

startGame()
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
<input type="submit" id="btn" />
```

However, this is not not easily scalable - you have all the logic based on `m` in the same function and adding handling for more will lead to more and more `if/else` statements making the function ugly to read and maintain. You can instead separate the handlers for each value of `m`, place them where they can be looked up and then `startGame` will merely act as a dispatch without needing to know what should happen:

```js
let m = 1;

let handlers = new Map();

handlers.set(1, function() {
  document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = "START PAGE"; 
  document.querySelector("#btn").value = 'Go to map 2';
  document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", map2);
  function map2() {
    m = 2;
    startGame();
  }
})

handlers.set(2, function() {
  document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = "SUCCESS!!!"; 
})

function defaultErrorHandler() {
  document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = "Nothing works";
}

function startGame() {
  //fetch handler or if that fails, use the default error
  const handler = handlers.get(m) || defaultErrorHandler;
  
  //execute handler
  handler();
}

startGame()
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
<input type="submit" id="btn" />
```

Now `startGame` doesn't need to change at all, each piece of logic is also self contained and can be edited in isolation.